# Unable to stream mp4 videos uploaded on Google Cloud Bucket

Tags: html, google-cloud-platform, cloud, video-streaming

I have `public to the internet` Google Cloud Storage Bucket where I have a bunch of .jpg and .mp4 files file

[image]

but when I try to access the file using img and video tags, the image shows up but the video player shows `No video with the supported format or MIME type found`

```
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <h1>The video element</h1>
    
    <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket-ath/6d1b8c235930b902f4ac033b1731d2f5.jpg" 
    alt="ninja"
    width="20%"
    />
    
    
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket-ath/2-%20Built-in%20Validators.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Did you try to get the video on your desktop and validate it if it works correctly? Can you also share all the metadata of the video object?

Comment: Have you tried getting public url using [CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/php/googlestorage/public_access#serving_files_directly_from_google_cloud_storage) method?

Comment: My guess is the video URL is incorrect. Use the browser inspect (debugger) feature, go to the Network tab, refresh the page and look for errors and verify the response headers are correct.